# Adding a 'Minimize' button to JTabbedPane Tab Bar

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I've searched extensively to solutions for this but haven't found anything that really achieves what I'm trying to do, the closest thing I could find was the solution posted at the bottom of this thread: http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/12267-how-add-jbutton-tabbed-pane-headder.html .

However because the JTabbedPane I'm using is inside a JSplitPane, it's size can increase/decrease, so using that solution doesn't work as the button stays static.

Below is an image of where I would like the place the component, similar to how eclipse has a minimize button on it's pop out views.

[image]

Is this possible without creating a custom JTabbedPane component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need this button to hide?

Why don't you set `splitpane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);`?

With this line you can hide the bottom with an arrow of the splitpane.

Comment: That seems to work rather well, it's a shame it's quite small though.